# Безопасно расширить плагин jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Работаю с плагином dateRangePicker.
Функциональности не хватает. Хочу дописать свои фидбеки.
Вопрос: Как это сделать не влезая в плагин? 
То есть отдельным файлом, чтобы все лежало. Возможно ли такое?
По сути нужно переписать  несколько функций внутри и добавить свою опцию в объект настроек. Спасибо.

Comment: А что значит аббревиатура "такое, спс"?

Comment: @0xdb, эта аббревиатура означает что я проявила невнимательность и не почистила свой текст после дополнения. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не всегда возможно.

Посмотрите в исходники плагина.
Если какие-то внутренние функции доступны глобально, их можно переопределить и вернуть из них что-то, что вам нужно.
Можно сделать прокси для каких-то функций.

В качестве примера: мы хотим расширить браузерную `document.createElement`, чтобы на запрос `document.createElement()` создавался див.

```
var documentCreateElement = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function (tagName) {
  if (tagName === undefined) {
    tagName = 'div';
  }
  return documentCreateElement.call(this, tagName);
};
```